# Django model field validator function used for update or insert

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

Is there a way of figuring out inside a Django model field validator function if it used for update or insert?

Comment: The short answer is no. What are you trying to achieve? There's might be a better approach than trying to use validators, e.g. checking the pk in the clean method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. A validator is simply a callable that takes a value and checks it. It has no access to the field or instance being validated, so it is impossible to tell whether it is a new or existing instance.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to update/insert a second object of a different type when my primary object gets saved. I want problems with saving the second object to appear as an error in the foreign key field of the primary object which points to it. This is why I used a validator and this is why I need to know when doing the validating if it's an update or insert

Comment: You could try writing a [`clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method for the model, but that won't let you assign the error to a specific field. Alternatively, you could use a model form, then you can assign [errors to a specific field in the `clean` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but I generally use self.pk to determine whether a model has already been saved or not. If there's no primary key, I can assume it's an insert.

Comment: In the clean method, you would use: self.instance.pk