# Django form field validation - How to tell if operation is insert or update?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

I'm trying to do this in Django: 
When saving an object in the Admin I want to save also another object of a different type based on one of the fields in my fist object.
In order to do this I must check if that second object already exists and return an validation error only for the particular field in the first object if it does.
My problem is that I want the validation error to appear in the field only if the operation is insert.

How do I display a validation error for a particular admin form field based on knowing if the operation is update or insert?

P.S. I know that for a model validation this is impossible since the validator only takes the value parameter, but I think it should be possible for form validation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This ca be done by writing a clean_[name_of_field] method in a Django Admin Form. The insert or update operation can be checked by testing self.instance.pk.

```
class EntityAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_field(self):
        field = self.cleaned_data['field']
        insert = self.instance.pk == None
        if insert:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Some error message!')
        else:
            pass
        return field

class EntityAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EntityAdminForm
```

You have to use then the EntityAdmin class when registering the Entity model with the Django admin:

```
admin.site.register(Entity, EntityAdmin)
```

Comment: I tried a few different options on SO, this worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can write your [custom validation at the model level](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.clean):

```
#inside your class model ...
def clean(self):
    is_insert = self.pk is None
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError, NON_FIELD_ERRORS
    #do your business rules
    if is_insert:
        ...
        if __some_condition__ :
            raise ValidationError('Dups.')
```

Comment: Yes, but will the validation error appear only in the needed field?

Comment: ops! Sorry: Any ValidationError exceptions raised by Model.clean() will be stored in a special key error dictionary key: NON_FIELD_ERRORS. I'm also interested to bind validation to a field.

Comment: @albundy, follow this link:  https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16986 . And go back with news!

Comment: @albundy, review answer sample code, you can know if it is a insert or udate through `self.pk is None` avaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model form for your model. In the `clean` method, you can set errors for specific fields.

See the docs for [cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) for more information.

Comment: Yes, I know you can do that, but how do you know in the clean method if the operation is update or insert?

Comment: If you know you can do that, then why ask "how do I display a validation error for a particular admin form field"? Andrew already told you [on your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665153/django-model-field-validator-function-used-for-update-or-insert) that you can check the pk to see whether the object has been saved, so I didn't think I needed to repeat him.

Comment: You only pasted part of my question :). You answered the first part, I did the second ;)

Comment: I always knew that you check for pk. But there was no pk. This was my problem. I did not know that in self.instance there the instance of the db entity

Answer (score 0):

That is (probably) not an exact answer, but i guess it might help.

Django Admin offers you to override `save` method with ModelAdmin.save_model method ([doc is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model))

Also Django api have a `get_or_create` method ([Doc is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)). It returns two values, first is the object and second one is a boolean value that represents whether object is created or not (updated an existing record).

Let me say you have `FirstObject` and `SecondObject`

In your related `admin.py` file:

```
class FirstObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...
...
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        s_obj, s_created = SecondObject.objects.get_or_create(..., defaults={...})
        if not s_created:
            #  second object already exists... We will raise validation error for our first object
            ...
```

For the rest, I do not have a clear idea about how to handle it. Since you have the form object at hand, you can call `form.fields{'somefield'].validate(value)` and [write a custom validation for admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin). You will probably override `clean` method and try to trigger a `raise ValidationError` from `ModelAdmin.save_model` method. you can call `validate` and pass a value from there...

You may dig django source to see how django handles this, and try to define some custom validaton steps.